# Algorithm Comparison for Influencers Ranking

Tags: machine-learning, python, algorithms, ranking

I am working on ranking social influencers on Instagram according to their influential power with the metrics collected below.

Metrics collected:

- username
- categories (the niche the influencer is in)
- influencer_type
- followers follower grow, follower_growth_rate
- highlightReelCount, igtvVideoCount, postsCount
- avg_likes, avg_comments
- likes_comments_ratio (comments per 100 likes, used as an authentic indicator)
- engagement_rate
- authentic_engagement (the number of likes and comments that come from real people）
- post_per_week
- 1/post_like,1/post_comment (total 12 latest posts)
- 1/igtv_likes, 1/igtv_comment (total 12 latest igtvs)

Here's what the data looks like:
[Sample_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7fEm.png)

The expected results would be something like this and to be shown to brands for them to choose their respective influencers:
[Expected_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYVDP.png)

After doing some research, I found a few ranking algorithm approaches which are:

1. Compute the score for influential power with [Multi-Criteria Decision Making (MCDM)](https://towardsdatascience.com/ranking-algorithms-know-your-multi-criteria-decision-solving-techniques-20949198f23e) and rank them with regression
2. Classified influencers through influencer type and rank them through probability
3. Compute the score for influential power with Multi-Criteria Decision Making (MCDM) and rank them with machine learning models like Support Vector Machine (SVM), Decision Tree and Deep Neural Network
4. Learning to rank algorithms like [CatBoost](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-quickstart)
5. [Trending algorithm](https://www.evanmiller.org/deriving-the-reddit-formula.html)

I would like to ask **which algorithm from the 5 options above is more suitable for this project and could you compare and provide the reasons for it**? Any ideas will be much appreciated!